# how to make a Ext gwt Grid movable?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, extjs

I have created a simple grid widget but it sticks to the browser window. How o I make it movable i.e draggable

Comment: hmm..is there anyway to resize the widget according to browser size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it drawable, add it first to a (smartgwt) window.